# Как обновить массив внутри json в postgres

Tags: postgresql

Комманда

```
update table set columnWithJSON = jsonb_set(columnWithJSON, '{fieldInThisJSON}', 'newValueForThisField') where id='someId';
```

Обновит поле со сторокой.

А как обновить поле содержащее массив строк?

Если JSON такой: `{"array": ["someString1", "someString2"], "name": "SomeName", "id": "someID"}`
Как легко и непринужденно обновить поле array без распаковки всего json. Может есть пример использования функций типа jsonb_set только для массива? При этом на вход подавать просто новый массив

UPD: В результате предполагается такой JSON: `{"array": ["newString1", "newString2"], "name": "SomeName", "id": "someID"}`

Есть ли вообще фукнция типа

```
jsonb_somefunc(someJSONColumn, '{fieldWithArray}', '[newString1 newString2]')
```

Или что то типа того

Которя сделает желаемый json.

Answer (score 0):

jsonb_set вторым параметром принимает путь к необходимому ключу внутри структуры json, пример можете посмотреть в данном ответе:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype

Официальная документация: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: Спасибо, нашел ответ на свой вопрос но забыл здесь на него ответить

Answer (score 0):

```
update table set json_column=json_column || {"somefield":"somevalue"};
```

Обновляет только те поля в json столбце postgres, которые указаны в json этой команды